# Illegal State exception while trying to read an excel file

Tags: java, excel, parsing, apache-poi

I try to read an excel file with Apache POI library and get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
>     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:845)
>     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getRichStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:294)
>     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:246)
>     at com.ge.aviation.TeamDataProcessor.process(TeamDataProcessor.java:174)
>     at com.ge.aviation.BatchCall$1.run(BatchCall.java:30)
>     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

I want to read the numerical value in cells as a text value. My numerical values in excel are 9 digit numerals (like: 108010407).

I read excel simply like this:

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(columnNumber)
```

But it is read as "1.08010407E8" instead of "108010407" and I use this value as an id. To solve my problem what kind of approach should I take?

Note: It doesn't help when I change the cell-type like this:

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sample source.

```
            switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                case org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    data = cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString();
                    break;
                case org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    data = Integer.toString((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
            }
```

javadoc link : http://javafind.net/library/13/poi-3.10-FINAL/docs/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getCellType()

Comment: You'd be better off using DataFormatter rather than Integer.toString, the former will apply the Excel formatting rules which apply to the cell